# Glassfish not seeing my handler-chain.xml

Tags: glassfish, config

When setting up my first handler chain I followed many guides, but only some of them were specific where to put the handler-chain.xml. The spec said in the class path.

So I tried to put them in the same dir as my webservice or even my root but I keep getting:

handler file handler-chain.xml not found.

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After just copying and pasting my handler-chain.xml around I found that it worked if I put the file into web pages/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: I had the same problem with Glassfish 4.1, this solved it. Thanks !